# .PNG images and icons are not supporting in centos7 server

Tags: imagemagick, centos7

I hosted web application(php) on cloud centos7 server .Everything is working fine but .PNG images and icons are not displaying in my application. Only .JPG images are displaying. I also installed Imagemagick then also it is not working

Comment: Have you installed `libpng-dev` and `zlib`?

Comment: yes,i have installed